# add multiple values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a table in the way shown below. Can we create in this way? (If Yes)

Table_name: Sample

```
product_id|   product_name| category   |
    1     |   Sample1     |  1|2|3     |
    2     |   sample2     |  4|5|6     |
```

where category filed which contains multiple values.

& how we can search for category 4 comes  in which row of the table.

Comment: No... You cannot create. Instead you can modularize the table and use a foreign key relation between these two tables.

Comment: @Anand, Everyone's suggestions are to do it a different way. Do you INSIST on doing it the wrong way?

Comment: This is not wrong - depending on the nature of what he is trying to achieve. If category will be representative of a small pool of values then the method is incorrect, create second table with foreign key. If however a Product had 1 million values, then making this a BLOB field and storing the values in one row would be more efficient both in data size and SQL optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot create nested table. And the thing on your mind is not a good idea to design table like that. You should have two tables (*exactly three which holds the description if the category*). One is for the `product` and the second table holds the *category for each product*. Example design would look like this,

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
    ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Category
(
    CategoryID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryName VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Product_Category
(
    RecordD INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryID INT,
    ProductID INT,
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE(CategoryID, ProductID)
);
```

and Populate Sample Records

```
INSERT Category VALUES (1, 'Fruit');
INSERT Category VALUES (2, 'Vegetable');

INSERT Product VALUES (1, 'Apple');
INSERT Product VALUES (2, 'Banana');
INSERT Product VALUES (3, 'Cabbage');
INSERT Product VALUES (4, 'Squash');
INSERT Product VALUES (5, 'Tomato');

INSERT Product_Category (CategoryID, ProductID) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT Product_Category (CategoryID, ProductID) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT Product_Category (CategoryID, ProductID) VALUES (2,3);
INSERT Product_Category (CategoryID, ProductID) VALUES (2,4);
INSERT Product_Category (CategoryID, ProductID) VALUES (1,5);
INSERT Product_Category (CategoryID, ProductID) VALUES (2,5);
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with records included*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0e2/3)

sample queries

```
-- NORMAL QUERY
SELECT  a.ProductName, c.CategoryName
FROM    Product a
        INNER JOIN Product_category b
          ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
        INNER JOIN Category c
          ON b.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
ORDER BY ProductName;

-- If you want catgoryName to be comma separated
SELECT  a.ProductName, GROUP_CONCAT(c.CategoryName) CategoryList
FROM    Product a
        INNER JOIN Product_category b
          ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
        INNER JOIN Category c
          ON b.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
GROUP BY ProductName
ORDER BY ProductName;
```

Comment: What is the point of this RecordID? (CategoryID, ProductID) would seem to be a fine primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those are strings in the form of `<item>|<item>|<item>`, you can, but it would be a better idea to give each category its own row relating to `product_id` and `product_name`. That way you can get better performance and have a more 'natural' structure so that you wouldn't have to do queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sample
WHERE category LIKE '%4|%' OR category LIKE '%|4|%' or category LIKE '%|4%'
```

in order to retrieve the data. A slightly better solution would be to surround all fields with pipes - if you have the ability to modify these strings beforehand, creating fields in this manner will make dealing with cases where `4` appears in the middle or at the beginning the same (e.g. `|4|5|6|` could be queried the same way as `|3|4|5`).

A more natural structure would be something like:

```
product_id|   product_name| category |
    1     |   Sample1     |  1       |
    1     |   Sample1     |  2       |
    1     |   Sample1     |  3       |
    2     |   sample2     |  4       |
    2     |   sample2     |  5       |
    2     |   sample2     |  6       |
```

Comment: what if `4` happens to be first? the WHERE clause should be `WHERE category LIKE '4|%' OR category LIKE '%|4|%' OR category LIKE '%|4'`.

Comment: @Vikdor Totally agree - that's why I put in the line noting that if he were creating the table like that, he should add pipes around all elements (I'll clarify to make that clear). I interpreted this more as a design question - happy to delete if not appropriate.

Comment: no, I just added to your answer. btw, I am not the downvoter, just to be clear :)

Comment: @Vikdor Added your suggested query in the example and made the following section describe what I was aiming for. Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: @Vikdor Ah gotcha. Oh well, can't please them all :) Thanks for the input though - good catch.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be one-to-many relationship between product and category and so you should normalize the category details into a different table as follows:

- product: product_id, product_name.
- product_categories: product_id, category_id

Then your product_categories table would be

```
product_id | category_id
         1 | 1
         1 | 2
         1 | 3
         2 | 4
         2 | 5
         2 | 6
```

Then a simple select statement JOINING the product table with product_categories table will give you all products in a given category.

Comment: In exchange for fixing my suggestion, I'll counter the rogue downvoter :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate table for categories:

table_categories

```
product_id| category   |
    1     |  1         |
    1     |  2         |
    1     |  3         |
    2     |  4         |
    2     |  5         |
    2     |  6         |
```

Then you can search like this:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name
FROM table_products p JOIN table_categories c
ON p.product_id = c.product_id
WHERE c.category = 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You need another table to represent the many-to-many relation. You should not insert multiple values into one column.

```
CREATE TABLE products (product_id, product_name)
CREATE TABLE product_category (product_id, category_id)

INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name) VALUES (1, 'Sample1');
INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name) VALUES (2, 'Sample2');

INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id) VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id) VALUES (2, 5);
INSERT INTO product_category (product_id, category_id) VALUES (2, 6);
```

To retrieve all products in category 4:

```
SELECT 
  products.* 
FROM 
  products 
INNER JOIN 
  product_category 
ON 
  products.product_id = product_category.product_id 
WHERE 
  product_category.category_id = 4;
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, in fact we do this by making 'category' (as an example) a BLOB, and thus allowing the ability to store very large subsets of data on one row. This allows a single connection and one query, which is far more optimized.

The only way to process it then - would be to actually do so on the 'Client Side'.
You may not want to use LIKE if the data in the field becomes to much.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create two tables;
Table one

```
product_id|   product_name|
    1     |   Sample1     |
    2     |   sample2     |
```

Table two

```
category_id| product_id|  category  |
    1      |     1     |      1     |
    2      |     1     |      2     |
    3      |     1     |      3     |
    4      |     2     |      4     |
    5      |     2     |      5     |
    6      |     2     |      6     |
```