# Having more than one value inserted into the same column

Tags: mysql

I have a webapp that I'm building. This webapp will take as input some products (cars, motos, boats, houses, etc...) and each product will have one or more photos associated with it. The id of each of photo is generated by the `uniqid()` function of php.

My problem is:**I can't seem to fit more than two `id_photos` into the same column**

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| carid     | int(11)                                  | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand     | enum('Alfa Romeo','Aston Martin','Audi') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| color     | varchar(20)                              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type      | enum('gasoline','diesel','eletric')      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price     | mediumint(8) unsigned                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mileage   | mediumint(8) unsigned                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| model     | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year      | year(4)                                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id_photos | varchar(30)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What I would like to happen is something like this: `INSERT INTO cars(id_photos) values ('id_1st_photo', 'id_2nd_photo')`

Ending up having something like this:

```
|    60 | Audi       | Yellow | diesel | 252352 | 1234112 | R8    | 1990 | id_1st_photo  id_2nd_photo     |
```

Eventually I would have to grab those photos from the folders they are in which is something like this: `/var/www/website/$login/photos/id_of_photo` with the query `select id_photos from cars where carid=$id`.

You may found some `data types` that is not proprelly good for the data that the server will receive but I'm one week into mysql and I'll worry about `data types` later on.

First of all I don't know if that is possible, if it's not how can I design something to work like that?

I have found this question that is quite the same of mine but I can't seem to implement something like this: [add multiple values in one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487671/add-multiple-values-in-one-column)

Comment: id_photos column length is 30 . Please increase the value

Comment: The approach of the linked question can be implemented for your problem: Remove id_photos from your table. Create a new table with two columns: carid and id_photo. The later table gets one row for each photo id you insert. If you want a "complete" dataset, you have to use JOIN and/or/ GROUP BY. Putting more than one value into a column in general prevents or at least hinders efficient querying of that column.

Comment: @Sirko I see your approach but how will the server know that a certain photo belongs to a certain user? Lets say that this user adds two cars into the website. How will the server know which photos is from the first car and the photos from the second car?

Comment: @Sirko Ohhhh. The car id. Would you care to answer the question so I can upvote it and set it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily adapt the approach in the linked question and even remove one table needed:

You first table stays almost the same, but has the `id_photos` column removed:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| carid     | int(11)                                  | NO   | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand     | enum('Alfa Romeo','Aston Martin','Audi') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| color     | varchar(20)                              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type      | enum('gasoline','diesel','eletric')      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price     | mediumint(8) unsigned                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mileage   | mediumint(8) unsigned                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| model     | text                                     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year      | year(4)                                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Then you'll add a second table to store the links to the photo ids:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| carid     | int(11)                                  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_photos | varchar(30)                              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Both tables are linked by the field `carid` (You should even make `carid` in the second table a foreign key pointing to the one in the first table).

Each `id_photos` then results in a new row in the second table.

To query the data you probably need a `JOIN` between both tables and maybe a `GROUP BY` to reduce the result to one row per `carid` again, but this depends on the other usecases.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the concatenated values into a field. But it is not a good practice. You can create another table with foreign key having the id of the parent table.

Comment: Altough your answer is good I marked Sirko answer as correct because it's more complete and has the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the string formatted woth multiple photo name

```
INSERT INTO cars(id_photos) values ('id_1st_photo, id_2nd_photo')
```

In this way you don'have a well normalized database structure so you have problem when retrive the singole foto name ..

i suggest you of normalize the id_photo column in a separata table with reference to the master table  and in this way store each single photo in one row